# Django/DRY: Avoid repetition in template

Tags: django

Anyone know how to avoid this repetition my template? I tried it with a for loop, but it didn't work out.

```
<p>
  Current:<br>
  {% for event in states.current %}
    <a href="{% url 'ambassadors:event' organizer=event.organizer.slug event=event.slug %}">{{ event.name }}</a>
  {% endfor %}
</p>

<p>
  Past:<br>
  {% for event in states.past %}
    <a href="{% url 'ambassadors:event' organizer=event.organizer.slug event=event.slug %}">{{ event.name }}</a>
  {% endfor %}
</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solution: set the proper context data structure in your view:

```
def yourview(request, ...):
   # code here
   context = {
      # other stuff here

      "states_data": [
         # (label, events)
         ("Current", states.current()),
         ("Past", states.past())), 
         ]
   }
```

Then in your template:

```
    {% for label, events in states_data %}
    <p>
      {{ label }}
      {% for event in events %}
        <a href="{% url 'ambassadors:event' organizer=event.organizer.slug event=event.slug %}">{{ event.name }}</a>
      {% endfor %}
   </p>
   {% endfor %}
```